# While trying to update the Xcode I am getting the error as "update is not available for this Apple ID" in Appstore

Tags: ios, xcode, tvos, xcode10

I am getting the error as "This update is not available for this Apple ID either because it was bought by a different user or the item was refunded or cancelled."

But I signed with the account which I am used to setup my machine.Here I can't able to edit my account in AppStore. How to edit my accout in AppStore. [image]

Comment: When you buy an app, even if it's free, it's linked to an iCloud Account (always imagine that it was maybe free during a short period of time, and you don't want user to just copy/paste it to share it to others after the free period). It seems that XCode was "bought" by another account. Remove XCode and Reinstall it. You can download it there https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ it's often faster and doesn't link the app with an iCloud Account without deleting the previous one yet if you are "scared".

Answer (score 0):

Xcode of the current mac was downloaded with some other apple ID. So it's apple's policy to update the existing app you need to sign in with the same ID that was used for downloading for the first time.

The solution is to uninstall xcode and download as a new with your account. Or else you can download the dmg file from [apple site](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?name=Xcode) and install (by double-clicking on .dmg file). Replace existing xcode inside application folder.

Comment: Kindly suggest any other way without deleting the application

Comment: Download .dmg file of xcode from [apple developer site](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?name=Xcode) and install (by double-clicking on .dmg file). Replace existing xcode inside application folder.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! You seem to be asking how to enter a new Apple ID in that textbox: it's showing a different ID, and you need to enter your own. Yeah?

1. With the App Store open, at the menu, go to Store -> Sign Out.
2. Then, back at the menu, go to Store -> Sign In.

Once you've signed in with your own account, you'll be able to update your copy of Xcode in the normal manner.